# Insert a dynamic value into text string on specific WooCommerce email template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I am modifying one of the WooCommerce email templates and adding text based on what payment method is used:

```
if ( 'bacs' == $order->get_payment_method() ){
    echo "We are awaiting payment" ;
    echo $order->get_order_number();
}
elseif ( 'paypal' == $order->get_payment_method() )  {
    echo "Text2";
}
else {
    echo "Text3;
}
```

I need to add the order ID into the first text (for BACS), so that it would display:

We are awaiting payment. Order reference: 1234 (your order number).

How can I add the order number into my plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to incorporate a variable value in a displayed text string as follows:

```
if ( 'bacs' === $order->get_payment_method() ) {
    printf( __("We are awaiting payment. Order reference: %s (your order number).", "woocommerce"), $order->get_order_number() );
} elseif ( 'paypal' === $order->get_payment_method() ) {
    echo __("Text2", "woocommerce");
} else {
    echo __("Text3", "woocommerce");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add string using `.` notation in php.

like with `"previous string".$order->get_order_number()` , you can append order number to preceding string.

```
if ( 'bacs' == $order->get_payment_method() ) {
    echo "We are awaiting payment. Order reference: ".$order->get_order_number();

} elseif ( 'paypal' == $order->get_payment_method() ) {
    echo "Text2";
} else {
    echo "Text3";
}
```

Comment: Please, add explainations.